# Add some fields automatically to all the migrations in prisma

Tags: prisma

I have around 20 data models and all these models needs `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields. Is there anyway to add these fields automatically for existing and future models when I run `prisma migrate` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to automatically add a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` field automatically to all the models.

If you can create a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) explaining your use case, prisma's engineering and product team can have a look and can prioritise it if other people also require the functionality.